# How do I just obtain relevant XML in ruby (ROR)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I have the following XML :

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<GetCustomerCentreDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <GetCustomerCentreDetailsResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/*****">
        <a:CustomerCentre>
            <a:CustomerCentreName>2 aaaaa Way </a:CustomerCentreName>     
            <a:CustomerCentreNumber>2</a:CustomerCentreNumber>
        </a:CustomerCentre>
        <a:CustomerCentre>
            <a:CustomerCentreName>Test Centre </a:CustomerCentreName>
            <a:CustomerCentreNumber>1</a:CustomerCentreNumber>
        </a:CustomerCentre>
    </GetCustomerCentreDetailsResult>
</GetCustomerCentreDetailsResponse>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**All I want is the two CustomerCentres**. And to display them. ( and add them to a Hash or something so i can access their data.)

My attempts have been unsucessful, as I cannot ignore the rest of the xml, plus Im not sure im doing it right.

Help would be apprieciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nokogiri is your friend for this one, as it parses XML really nicely:  http://nokogiri.org/

Example:

```
   #auth_info = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://tempuri.org"))
   #info = auth_info.xpath('//CustomerCentreName').text
```

Comment: Ill give it a try, thanks. Been using a few different ones with no success. When I identify which one i want, it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

The code I used is as follows:  (thanks for pointing me to Nokogiri)

```
reader = Nokogiri::XML::Reader(@response.to_xml)


reader.each do |node|
  # node is an instance of Nokogiri::XML::Reader
  if node.name == "#text"
    puts node.value
  end
end
```